# get value from funcA to funcB - promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to get the value `sum` from `funcA` to `funcb` but
I get `NaN`.

I'm trying to access the `sum` value from `funcA` by give the function a let value but the sum value don't pass to `f2`.

Where is my mistake?

```
let f1 = function funcA(arr)
{
    let prom = new Promise(resolve =>{
        let sum = 0
        arr.map(x => 
            {
                x.forEach(num =>
                    {
                        sum += num
                    })
            })
        setTimeout( () => resolve(sum) ,2000 )
    })
    return prom
}


f1([[1,6,3,9],[6,12,5,21],[4,11,23,1]]).then(x => console.log(x))


let f2 = function funcB(sum)
{
    let prom = new Promise(resolve => {
            let dubSUm = sum * 2
            setTimeout( () => resolve(dubSUm), 3000 )
    })
    return prom
}

f2().then(x => console.log(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `f2` function takes the "sum" (presumably intended as the output of the Promise returned by `f1`) as an argument - but in your example you don't provide it.

You've already done most of the "hard work", you just need to chain the promises - which you can do like this:

```
f1([[1,6,3,9],[6,12,5,21],[4,11,23,1]])
  .then(f2)
  .then((x) => console.log(x))
```

Comment: but i cant pass the sum value to f2 in the funcB function

f1([[1,6,3,9],[6,12,5,21],[4,11,23,1]])
.then((x) => console.log(x))
.then(f2 => f2 = function funcB(sum)
{
    let prom = new Promise(resolve => {
            let dubSum = sum * 2
            setTimeout( () => resolve(dubSum), 2000 )
    })
    return prom
})

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do in that code. But I can guarantee that, with `f1` and `f2` as defined in your question, then the code shown in my answer works, and logs `204` as you presumably wanted.